# Загрузка сообщений из файла только за определенное время(последний час)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, дата, время

Есть файл `json`, в котором хранятся сообщения. Они имеют такой вид

```
[
    {
        "time": "1499200189",
        "user": "qwe",
        "message": "w"
    },
]
```

На страницу мне нужно выгружать только сообщения за последний час. Подскажите, как это реализовать?
Вот как я получаю все сообщения из файла

```
$.getJSON('data/messages.json', callback)
     for (var i = 0; i < respond.length; i++) {
            var data = respond[i];
```

Пытаюсь узнать разницу между датами вот так, но это бред, поскольку в `time` время каждого сообщения в файле. Помогите пожалуйста.Если есть вариант как получать из файла сообщения которые записаны в течении последнего часа, буду рад услышать!

```
var now  = Date.now();
var time = (data.time);
var diff = (now - time);
```

Comment: сразу бы уже кидали все задачи, которые за вас нужно решить)

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich Я не прошу решить за меня, я прошу предложить варианты как мне поступить , или что я делаю не так)

Answer (score 1):

Здесь единственный вариант это загружать все данные из JSON-файла и пробегать по ним в цикле с определением разницы time в сообщении и текущим временем. Если менее 3600, то выводим это сообщение, если больше - пропускаем.

Другой момент, что хранить все сообщения в таком виде не самая лучшая идея, т.к. любой человек, который ориентируется в коде сможет вручную читать все сообщения ваших пользователей. А также это могут делать поисковые системы с публикацией результатов в свою выдачу))